# MariaDB SQL COUNT with two INNER JOINs taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

Edit: I have since learned about EXPLAIN. I have also manged to identify that the players_teams didn't have an index item in the query. I have added one to my query and it is now executing in less then a sec.

Comments would still be appreciated.

I have a query on a database that I am trying to write, it is supposed to return the number of games a player has played in a season.

I've been running into problems with the query returning multiple of entries with different games_id or different team_id.

I am finally getting the results I want but the query is now taking 3min to execute.

Here is the query so far (edited):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT schedule_player_status.id) AS ps_id
FROM schedule_player_status
INNER JOIN schedule ON schedule.id = schedule_player_status.ps_game_id
    AND schedule.s_season_id = ".$seasonID."
    AND schedule.s_datetime < NOW()
    AND schedule.s_type='GAME'
INNER JOIN players_teams ON players_teams.t_team_id = schedule_player_status.ps_team_id
    AND players_teams.t_season_id = ".$seasonID."
    AND players_teams.t_player_id = schedule_player_status.ps_player_id
    AND (players_teams.t_player_class = 'ROSTER' OR players_teams.t_player_class = 'SPARE')
WHERE schedule_player_status.ps_season_id=" . $seasonID . "
    AND schedule_player_status.ps_status = 'IN'
GROUP BY schedule_player_status.ps_player_id
```

It is part of a larger query (edited):

```
SELECT players.p_name, players.p_email, players.p_phone, players.p_dob, players.p_status, players_teams.t_player_position,
players.id AS playerID, teams.id AS teamID, teams.t_name, teams.t_div,

/*Count games played*/
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT schedule_player_status.id) AS gamesPlayed
FROM schedule_player_status
players_teams.t_player_class = 'SPARE')
INNER JOIN schedule ON schedule.id = schedule_player_status.ps_game_id
    AND schedule.s_season_id = ".$seasonID."
    AND schedule.s_datetime < NOW()
    AND schedule.s_type='GAME'
INNER JOIN players_teams ON players_teams.t_team_id = schedule_player_status.ps_team_id
    AND players_teams.t_season_id = ".$seasonID."
    AND players_teams.t_player_id = schedule_player_status.ps_player_id
    AND (players_teams.t_player_class = 'ROSTER' OR 
WHERE schedule_player_status.ps_season_id=".$seasonID."
    AND schedule_player_status.ps_status = 'IN'
    AND schedule_player_status.ps_player_id = playerID
) AS gamesPlayed,

/*Count goals by playerID*/
SUM(players_stats.s_goals) AS s_goals,

/*Count assists by playerID*/
SUM(players_stats.s_assists) AS s_assists,

/*Count PIMs by playerID*/
SUM(players_stats.s_pims) AS s_pims

FROM `players_teams`

LEFT JOIN `players` ON players.id = players_teams.t_player_id
LEFT JOIN `players_stats` ON players_stats.s_player_id = players.id 
    AND players_stats.s_season_id = ".$seasonID." 
    AND players_stats.s_team_id = players_teams.t_team_id
LEFT JOIN `teams` ON teams.id = players_teams.t_team_id AND teams.t_season_id = " . $seasonID . "

WHERE players_teams.t_season_id = ". $seasonID ." AND (players_teams.t_player_class = 'ROSTER' OR players_teams.t_player_class = 'SPARE')

GROUP BY playerID
```

When I execute the larger query it times out at 5min.

I'm sure the query structure is terrible, it is one of the first queries I ever written.

Thanks for any help provided.

Matt

Comment: Learn to use alias.  The long table names are very annoying.

Comment: Ha, I thought so too when typing them all the time!

Do I declare them in the SELECT part of the query?

Comment: `... FROM players_teams pt
LEFT JOIN players p ON p.id = pt.t_player_id
LEFT JOIN players_stats ps ON ps.s_player_id = p.id ...`

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely start doing that.